# Conditional sum stops working in second line in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am using a quite involved spreadsheet for RPG character creation. Unfortunately, a certain functionality does not fully work and I absolutely cannot explain why.

In [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FZZSWComWLJjxHvay1WQbisY2zS9fplvmS3objt8Uo8/edit?usp=sharing)
Worksheet2.C115 should be 4, as in

```
=if(and(C115=""),"",if(and(C115<>""),SUMIF($P$113:$CT$113,"ranks",P115:CT115)))
```

C115 is not empty, Q113 and U113 equal "ranks" and Q115 is 1 and U115 is 3. However, it is evaluated to 0. The same formula works in line 114, though.

In line 116 I have removed the first conditions and simplified the problem to

```
=SUMIF($P$113:$CT$113,"ranks",P116:CT116)
```

which still does not work and in line 117, I have limited the range to two fields to avoid spanning the merged field R112/113

```
=SUMIF($P$113:$Q$113,"ranks",P117:Q117)
```

still with no success.

As I said, I am out of ideas. Could this be an internal issue with Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are facing cell format issues. **`=SUMIF`** works only with cells that have numbers. if the cell is formatted as something else then **`=SUMIF`** won't work.

to fix your problem select range **P114:CU** and format it as **Number** / **Custom number** or **Automatic**

[image]

Comment: Wow. That is exactly the problem and I would never have found that. Thanks!
Is there a particular reason for that? It does not seem to be a problem with LibreCalc,

Comment: @mcandril I mentioned the reason in the first two sentences.